# Unable to Install openxlsx library in R

Tags: r, r-package, openxlsx

I have been trying to install "openxlsx" library in R. I have R 3.4.0 and tried installing "openxlsx" from cran and from package archive (local folder) as well but none of them let me install this package.  Below is the log message. Can someone please help.

```
> install.packages("C:/Users/rgowriga/Downloads/openxlsx_4.0.17.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
'\\...\rgowriga$\Documents'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
* installing *source* package 'openxlsx' ...
** package 'openxlsx' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs

*** arch - i386
C:/PF/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library/Rcpp/include"   -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
C:/PF/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library/Rcpp/include"   -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c helper_functions.cpp -o helper_functions.o
C:/PF/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library/Rcpp/include"   -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c load_workbook.cpp -o load_workbook.o
C:/PF/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library/Rcpp/include"   -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O3 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c openxlsx_init.c -o openxlsx_init.o
C:/PF/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library/Rcpp/include"   -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c read_workbook.cpp -o read_workbook.o
C:/PF/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library/Rcpp/include"   -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c write_data.cpp -o write_data.o
C:/PF/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library/Rcpp/include"   -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c write_file.cpp -o write_file.o
C:/PF/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library/Rcpp/include"   -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c write_file_2.cpp -o write_file_2.o
C:/PF/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++ -shared -s -static-libgcc -o openxlsx.dll tmp.def RcppExports.o helper_functions.o load_workbook.o openxlsx_init.o read_workbook.o write_data.o write_file.o write_file_2.o -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib/i386 -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/bin/i386 -lR
installing to C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library/openxlsx/libs/i386

*** arch - x64
C:/PF/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library/Rcpp/include"   -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
C:/PF/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library/Rcpp/include"   -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c helper_functions.cpp -o helper_functions.o
C:/PF/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library/Rcpp/include"   -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c load_workbook.cpp -o load_workbook.o
C:/PF/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library/Rcpp/include"   -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c openxlsx_init.c -o openxlsx_init.o
C:/PF/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library/Rcpp/include"   -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c read_workbook.cpp -o read_workbook.o
C:/PF/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library/Rcpp/include"   -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c write_data.cpp -o write_data.o
C:/PF/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library/Rcpp/include"   -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c write_file.cpp -o write_file.o
C:/PF/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library/Rcpp/include"   -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c write_file_2.cpp -o write_file_2.o
C:/PF/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++ -shared -s -static-libgcc -o openxlsx.dll tmp.def RcppExports.o helper_functions.o load_workbook.o openxlsx_init.o read_workbook.o write_data.o write_file.o write_file_2.o -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib/x64 -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/bin/x64 -lR
C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/bin/x64/R.dll: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'openxlsx'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library/openxlsx'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.0\library" "C:/Users/rgowriga/Downloads/openxlsx_4.0.17.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/rgowriga/Downloads/openxlsx_4.0.17.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: What does `shell("zip")` return if you run that in R?

Comment: '\\...\rgowriga$\Documents'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
  adding: - (deflated 0%)
PK  -

Comment: Sounds like your R library may be stored on a network drive. Check this article out, it might be able to help: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/203775903-Fixing-startup-error-where-manipulate-and-rstudio-packages-will-not-install-with-networked-drives